# Perl run command on remote system

Tags: ssh, perl

I need to run a series of commands on remote systems, but am having problems with perl staying logged in. I "can't" use the ssh or telnet command, as it is a service account logging in and has no password. I am trying this below, but the program ssh's into the system and doesn't exit until I ctl+d out.

```
system("ssh -qtt $server sudo cp /opt/uc4sand/bin/*.kstr /tmp/sand.kstr; sudo service uc4sand stop");
```

Comment: As far as I can see, the 2nd `sudo` would be executed locally, if its executed at all. Is that expected?

Answer (score 2):

problem solved with:

```
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new(
                $server,
                user    => 'user';
                ssh_arges => {
                        identity_files => [ '/home/account/.ssh/id_rsa ' ]
                        debug => 1,
                }

        ) or die "could not open connection $server";
```